# Laravel Eloquent Unique validation issue

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am currently trying to add a validation for the customer_no in the companies table.

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = Company::where('customer_no', '=', $this->get('customer_no'))->first();
    $id = $id['attributes']['id'];

    return [
        'customer_no' => 'required|unique:companies,customer_no,'.$id,
    ];

}
```

After adding a new company with an already existing customer_no I get the following error message from the unique database migration.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1062 Duplicate entry 'abc' for key 'companies_customer_no_unique' 
(SQL: update `companies` set `customer_no` = abc, `updated_at` = 2016-03-15 14:50:28 where `id` = 1)
```

But instead it should redirect me to the previous page and show the error message. This is already working for the required field and the variable $id contains the id of the company (checked with var_dump).

**Edit: (companyController Storage)**

```
    /**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  ManageCompanyRequest  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(ManageCompanyRequest $request)
{

    $company = $request->all();

    if(!(CompanyType::where('id','=',$request->company_type_id)->exists()  || CompanyType::where('name', 'like', $request->company_type_id)->exists()))
        $company['company_type_id'] = CompanyType::create(['name' => $request->company_type_id])->id;
    else if(CompanyType::where('name', 'like', $request->company_type_id)->exists())
        $company['company_type_id'] =  CompanyType::where('name', 'like', $request->company_type_id)->first(['id'])->id;
    $address = Address::create($request->all());

    $company['address_id'] = $address->id;

    Company::create($company);

    return redirect('companies');
}
```

**CompanyController Update:**

```
    /**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update(ManageCompanyRequest $request, $id)
{
    if(!(CompanyType::where('id','=',$request->company_type_id)->exists()  || CompanyType::where('name', 'like', $request->company_type_id)->exists()))
        $request->company_type_id = CompanyType::create(['name' => $request->company_type_id])->id;
    else if(CompanyType::where('name', 'like', $request->company_type_id)->exists())
        $request->company_type_id =  CompanyType::where('name', 'like', $request->company_type_id)->first(['id'])->id;

    $company = Company::find($id);
    Company::find($id)->update([
        'company_type_id'   => $request->company_type_id,
        'customer_no'       => $request->customer_no,
        'name'              => $request->name,
        'comment'           => $request->comment
    ]);


   Address::where('id', '=', $company->address_id)->update([
        'country_code_id'   => $request->country_code_id,
        'city'          => $request->city,
        'region'            => $request->region,
        'postal_code'       => $request->postal_code,
        'street'           => $request->street
    ]);


    return redirect('companies');
}
```

Comment: You can try to add a try catch statement in your method in your Controller. This wil prevent the code from generating such an ugly front-end error. Are you able to add the controller method to the code?

Comment: Do you need to supply the ID to the validation rule array? I thought just specificying 'customer_no' => 'required|unique:companies' would be enough. What you're doing with that rule is actually forcing the validator to IGNORE the supplied ID. See 'Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID': https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation

Comment: The ID is needed to edit existing companies. In order to update an entry I must ignore the customer_no for this specific entry. It is working for store without the except part, but isn't working for updates.
Added store() and update() of companyController.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the controller to redirect you back to the form, you need to update the validation. When you detect a conflict in the database (i.e. `customer_no` is not unique), you should do:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(['Error message here']);
```

E.g.

```
if(!(CompanyType::where('id','=',$request->company_type_id)->exists()  || CompanyType::where('name', 'like', $request->company_type_id)->exists()))
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(['Details are not unique']);
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround for my problem and I really appreciate it.
Anyways I would expect the validation rule: unique:companies,customer_no,'.$id,  to do exactly the same. Would be a much cleaner way to get the whole validation working.

Comment: Yep, that would work too. But since I didn't see you using Validation, I though you would want a workaround.